# Injection WCF proxy client using unity

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an asp.net mvc application and need to call wcf service in it. I've added service reference to the project. I use unity for dependency injection and want to inject wcf client. But it's not so simple because of System.ServiceModel.ClientBase. I did it this way.
This is an autogenerated proxy:

```
public partial class WcfServiceClient : 
    System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<WcfUnity.IWcfServiceClient>, 
    WcfUnity.IWcfServiceClient 
{
    //autogenerated constructors and methods
}
```

I created interface:

```
public interface ISimpleProxy : WcfUnity.IWcfServiceClient
{
    //duplication of methods' signatures
    void CloseConnection();
}
```

I extended WcfServiceClient using partial class:

```
public partial class WcfServiceClient : ISimpleProxy
{
    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

And inject it like this:

```
container.RegisterType<ISimpleProxy>(new InjectionFactory(c => new WcfServiceClient()));
```

So I don't have dependecies from ClientBase and there is no wcf stuff inside classes which use this wcf proxy. Does this solution have some disadvatages?

Comment: This solution is BAD. It is the responsibility of IOC to handle scope for you. `ClientBase` already implements `IDisposable`, so everything should be working fine without any work. Your code should only know about `ISimpleProxy` and you should let Unity handle `WcfServiceClient` logic.

Comment: @Aron, so do I need to delete CloseConnection() and use ISimpleProxy methods only?

Comment: My bad. What I mean is that `ISimpleProxy` should not exist. You should just have `IWcfServiceClient` in your code. You should register using `container.RegisterType<WcfServiceClient, IWcfServiceClient>(lifetimeManager);`. Then get rid of everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't, I use (mostly) the same approach.

I would recommend you making your interface inherit from `IDisposable`, because underlying `ClientBase<T>` is disposable. This way you won't need `CloseConnection`.

Comment: I don't think that is necessary. Unity should know that the `WcfServiceClient` implements `IDisposable` and should dispose it when the scope ends.

Comment: @Aron This approach works only when you're using scopes (and defer the disposal to Unity). We're not using scopes, because there's no clean way of integrating them, so we prefer direct disposal in code.

Comment: @oblomov86 yes, and I inject `Func<IBlahBlahClient>` so that it could be instantiated as many times as I need it to.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev firstly if you want to handle object life cycle, don't use IOC on that object (think about who the owner should be, RAII). Secondly I refuse to believe that you cannot use scopes in an ASP.Net MVC application. The obvious one would be per request scope.

Comment: @Aron I prefer using IoC on all services I depend on. That is especially beneficial when some kind of service I am planning to dispose myself has a lot of dependencies. Autofac even has a [special kind of relationship](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/owned-instances.html) for this pattern. And yes, while there is a per-request scope in asp.net mvc, we encountered some problems with its implementation (and not all my projects are asp.net or other request-based).